# How to generate Sitecore zip package from Visual Studio build process (or TDS)

Tags: tds, packages

Is it possible to generate a Sitecore zip installation package from a TDS project in a Visual Studio solution? Ideally, but not strictly, in a way that could run on a CI server.

Comment: What's more important to your question, that the CI server can get updated, or that the format of the package is specifically a zip package? I ask as TDS generates .update packages as standard and these can be installed as part of a CI process.

Comment: I'm aware of the update package generation feature of TDS, so my main question is can a zip package be created instead, or by some other means?

Comment: Can we run some other VS solution after TDS process completes - we could use the code mentioned here to generate the zip package -http://www.webdatasource.com/2011/08/exporting-and-importing-packages-from-sitecore-through-code-using-sitecore-api/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to create a standard .zip package from within Visual Studio/TDS but you can do that with Sitecore Rocks and there is an example here by Trevor Campbell: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/trevor_campbell/posts/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-creation. As seen in your answer to Joe, if that's all the functionality you really need, then that should be all you need to create a package easily from within Visual Studio. You can get Sitecore Rocks by going into Visual Studio and going to Tools--> Extensions and Updates --> Select Online --> Search for Sitecore Rocks. It should be the first selection in the list.

Comment: Can you automate this process so that the package is generated automatically after a build in VS ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's where my knowledge ends on making packages in Sitecore Rocks. You might be able to run a build script that may do that similar to how you would do that with TDS, but you would need to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I use a mixture of [Sitecore.Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship), TDS Update Package generation, and CURL to achieve CD from my CI servers.

Is there any reason why you want a zip package over an update package?

Comment: I want a zip package as I am building a marketplace module and it seems to be the convention that they are installed by a regular zip package.

Comment: You may want to look at using PSE.  You could expose an endpoint that runs a PS script that generates a zip package.  You would, of course, need to have your solution up and running on a Sitecore installation to do this.

Comment: Could I do that from within Visual Studio?